# how to display resource view in Fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have multiple user in a day. Each user has multiple events and sorting of event not working properly for multiple user.

So someone has implemented the resource view in fullcalendar then let me know how to do it?

Example : [Link](http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2014/08/11/fullcalendar-with-a-resource-day-view-v2-0-2/)

As i have used

```
$jy = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

This will not work for me. How should i do with new js.

What is the meaning of below code? When i comment this code then it print the resource column in title but not in event. 
But when i comment it my fullcalendar not working and also don't show any erorr.

```
 (function(factory) {
        if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            define([ 'jquery', 'moment' ], factory);
        }
        else {
            factory(jQuery, moment);
        }
    })
```

Comment: the resource view has its own complications, i would recommend you to have multiple calendar one for each user it's robust and tested as i had done it on one of my projects

Comment: i can't create new one each user . because there has already so much work has been done on it. i have update the source link which will give the solution. but i geting conflict on as my system used at widgets

Comment: the link you mentioned is the only way that i had tried in the past, it works great with 1.6.2 that i have tested

Comment: I have updated the post. Check and let me know.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/seankenny/fullcalendar/tree/v2

Comment: I have checked the same and i also check the demos and it is working perfect. but my system is using as widgets so i have used jQuey.noConflict(); so it is not working.